# Matching substring with different variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with authors, papers they've published and citation counts for each paper (as well as 71 other columns). I want to find the most cited authors. The problem is that some papers have multiple authors so each author is a substring. I can separate out the authors easily enough but I can't figure out how to aggregate each of their citations. Can anyone help?

### Here's the dataframe

```
    year   citation  author              paper_title
    2018       33    author1; author2    paper1
    2018       89    author2; author3    paper2
    2017       10    author4             paper3 
    2013       10    author2             paper4
    2014        9    author3             paper5
    2011        1    author5             paper7
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output`library(tidyverse); df1 %>% separate_rows(author) %>% group_by(author) %>% summarise(citation = sum(citation))`

Comment: Thanks for this. Still not getting the result I want but I think this general approach might be the way to go. The expected output is number of citations for each author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018, 2017),
citation = c(33,89),
author = c('author1; author2', 'author2; author3'),
paper_title = c('paper1', 'paper2'), stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- df %>% mutate(author=strsplit(author, "; ")) %>% 
  unnest(author) %>% group_by(author) %>% summarise(n_cit = sum(citation))
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets me exactly what i want!

Comment: @NewtoRcode happy to help and would be even happier to see an upvote or a check mark!

Comment: I upvoted but it said it wouldn't register because I have less than 15 points or something